# Excel has ~1 million rows ( 2016 Version ) but Pasting content only fills 65522 rows

Tags: excel, csv, copy-paste

I am trying to paste `512 thousand` lines of `CSV` formatted data in an `EXCEL` file.
Problem is that whenever I try to paste it by selecting the `A1` cell, I get this warning:

[image]

And I end up with only `65522 thousand` out of the `512 thousand` lines being pasted in the file.

What could potentially be the problem here? Any Suggestions?
Thank you in advance for your time and efforts.

Comment: Paste it into a text file; then **import** the file using one of the standard methods.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thank you so much for the Information and your help, that's what I was looking for!